# The number of people who do not know an odd number of people

Tags: grammar

See the linked question on Math SE:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1781353/187867

The OP and others were confused about whether "the number of people who do not know an odd number of people" refers to

1. People who know an even number of people, or
2. People for whom the number of people they do not know is odd.

I'm aware that option 1 is the correct choice, and I answered the question without thinking twice. But someone whose first language wasn't English had no idea how to interpret it, and I attempted to explain why option 1 was correct. My attempt was poor. Can anyone here do better?

Comment: It is ambiguous -- both answers are equally "correct".

Comment: @HotLicks I disagree. I read it as (do not) (know an odd number of people). (Do not know) (an odd number of people) sets off my "not English!" alarm.

Comment: Actually, my first interpretation would be #2, but I can see it would be argued either way.  A lot has to do with the extent to which you tend to aggregate towards the left vs the right.

Comment: @HotLicks well with the alternative interpretation the answer to the question is actually yes, but phrasing it that way seems bizarre. In that case you'd have a graph with an edge between two people if they do not know each other, and the number of vertices incident to an odd number of edges has to be even. But I can't imagine anyone asking the question and intending that answer, and I still can't convince myself that that could possibly be correct.

Comment: Actually, as a math problem that might make a lot of sense, as the answer would be "obvious" even if the number of participants and their relationships were somehow obfuscated.  But the statement **is** ambiguous, so it's very poor math from a preciseness standpoint.

Comment: In mathematics one can assume that if A knows B, then B knows A. But this is English, and knowing a person is not a symmetric relation in English. That pretty much kills off the simple graph solution; you'd need directed edges at least. As for the unclarity, it's par for the course when you have a negative and two different quantities that have to be calculated at runtime in a short sentence with multiple phrasal repetitions. I.e, it isn't supposed to be clear -- it's confusingly written -- and it's not surprising that somebody couldn't understand it.

Comment: Without the  context of the mathematical problem, considering the question just as English semantics, I'd say the expression is ambiguous and the second interpretation is more plausible.  The mathematical context often disambiguates such things, in that only one of the interpretations makes sense, but the English language, by itself, isn't up to that task.

Comment: As a question of grammar, the ambiguity seems obvious.  As a question of *pragmatics*, how can one count unknown people?  Do we count everyone alive today or everyone who lived throughout history?  Do we count souls as yet unborn or as yet unconceived?  Do we count fictional characters and, if so, those yet unwritten?  A number that cannot, even in principle, be counted is a number that cannot be designated either even or odd.  That number of people of whom I personally have no knowledge is infinite.

Comment: Everybody who knows one person knows an odd number of people. Everybody knows at least one person. Therefore, everybody knows an odd number of people.

Comment: @Gary well I left out of my quote that we're only considering people at a party.

Comment: Option 2 is the correct choice, as can be deduced from the fact that the answer to the linked question is "yes" if you choose option 2, and "no" if you choose option 1. Both answers to the linked question are wrong, because the poser of the question meant option 2.

Comment: @Peter there's no reason for the answer of the question to be yes or no. It is what it is. If the answer is yes, you prove it. If it's no, you provide a counterexample.

Comment: @Matt: I'm assuming that whoever posed the question wanted their students to come up with a proof, and not a counterexample. The counterexample is trivial. The proof actually tests whether they know enough graph theory to prove a relatively simple statement. Thus, reasoning by the motivations of math professors, the proof is by far the most likely intended answer to the question.

Comment: @Peter providing the counterexample is also a proof. Being able to come up with counterexamples is an extremely important skill in mathematics and it is often tested. It gives you the ability to tell what you should not try to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You knew it was true because of your background; you understand the question in the *context* it is given. Thus while there is nothing conclusively guiding you to one interpretation or the other in the grammar and syntax itself, you intuit the probable meaning based on the grammatical and syntactical formulations common to the context of the question. Your past experience informs your decision.

Answer (score 3):

Let us say that I (Andy) am in a room with Bob, Claire, Danielle and Em, and I only know Bob.

I know Bob. Bob, as one person, is an odd number of people. Hence it is perfectly defensible, when talking about the people in the room, to say "I know an odd number of people".

I do not Claire, Danielle, or Em. Claire, Danielle and Em are an odd number of people. Hence it is perfectly defensible, when talking about the people in the room, to say "I do not know an odd number of people".

Hence, both are equally valid, logically and grammatically.