# The number of people who do not know an odd number of people, part 2

Tags: grammar, dialects

The answers to the following question have puzzled me: [The number of people who do not know an odd number of people](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/339760/142967)

I am 100% certain that in whatever version of English I speak, the two sentences

> I do not know an odd number of people.

and

> The number of people I do not know is odd.

are unambiguous and cannot possibly have the same meaning. Is this specific to any dialects of English or is it really just my own idiosyncrasy?

Comment: The first is ambiguous, but they're both so bizarre and convoluted logically that it doesn't matter if they're ambiguous or not—nobody still has any idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Both are ambiguous, and it would be quite easy to take both to mean the same thing.

Comment: I can't imagine there are any *dialectical* differences here; the syntax is straightforward and the words' meanings are transparent and universally shared, as far as I'm aware. This is a question of pragmatics, and I don't think there's any conclusive way to settle the question in a context-free scenario, nor divide speakers into specific interpretive camps. If pragmatics governs, as I suspect, then the *actual* context of the utterance matters.

Comment: @Dan it's from a math problem. I have a PhD in math and I write/speak about math a lot, and as far as technical language goes this just seems like simple English to me.

Comment: What branch of math involves statements such as these? Are you referring to logic as math?

Comment: @Stan http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1781353/187867 It's graph theory.

Comment: I take both to mean the same thing.  “I don’t know 7 people” 7 is odd.    As far as the question on Math goes, if everyone at the party knows everyone else (including the famous author) and the author knows everyone except for one of the guests isn’t there just one person who doesn’t know an odd number of people assuming there is, in total, an odd number of people at the party.  The key whether “knowing” is defined to be a one-way relation or a two-way relation.

Comment: The ambiguity lies in whether or not you can conclude that you know an even number of people. Many people would. But alternatively, you might conclude that you do not not know an even number of people. I know not what to do about it, but I know what not to do about it.

Comment: @Dan I'm now convinced that the fact that they're unambiguous is indeed dependent on their use in a mathematical context. Perhaps you could post an answer elaborating on what you mean.

Comment: @Jim the most interesting graphs from a combinatorial point of view are the undirected simple graphs because there's a lot more you can prove about them than directed graphs. That is certainly the type of graph intended to be used in the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just to enumerate:

> I do not know an odd number of people.

- "An odd number" is an idiom meaning "a few".
- There are six people at this party that I do not know.  But if I do not know six then there are also five people that i do not know.  Five is odd, so I do not know an odd number of people.
- There are seven people at this party that I do not know.  Seven is odd.

> The number of people I do not know is odd.

- It is strange that, at this party of my "friends", I do not know twelve of them.  Don't you find that odd, too?
- There are seven people at this party that I do not know.  Seven is odd.

(And I suspect there are a few more interpretations.)

I'll add that one big reason there are so many ambiguous interpretations is that the sentences express a concept which is, uh, "odd" -- one for which there is not often reason for precise discussion.  English tends to pick up meanings and idioms which allow common concepts to be discussed concisely and accurately, but is apt to be less readily precise with obscure (and, dare I say, meaningless) concepts.